# Generators increasing the word metric

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be an infinite group with a finite generating set $T$ which is symmetric ($T=T^{-1}$) and let $|\cdot|$ be the corresponding word metric, i.e. $|g|$ is the minimal number of (not necessarily distinct) elements from $T$ one needs to multiply to get $g$.

Is it true that for every $g\in G$ there is a $t\in T$ such that $|gt|>|g|$?

Comment: I suppose it is easy to write a presentation of a group in which a rather long word $\alpha$ times every generator coincides with a shorter word but, of course, the difficult part is checking that the length of $\alpha$ is what it looks like.  Nevertheless I would put my money on a negative answer.

Comment: I cannot see why anyone would vote to close this question.  A short question does not necessarily mean lack of context.  Group theory is full of interesting straight-to-the-point questions and I am confident this is one such question.  Besides we already have a highly voted answer and there are at least two people (me + OP) yearning for another answer addressing a more stringent requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$ with $T=\{\pm2,\pm3\}$. Then $|1|=2$, and $|1+t|\leq 2$ for all $t\in T$.

Comment: Nice! But I suspect it is possible that $|gt|<|g|$, for every $t$.

Comment: I would also be interested to see if one can even obtain $|gt|<|g|$ for every $t\in T$.

Comment: For strict inequality, just take a cyclic group of even order $n$, generated by $\{g,g^{-1}\}$, and look at $g^{n/2}$.

Comment: Just realized you want an infinite group. Then I think this answer can be modified to give the strict inequality: take $\mathbb{Z}$ with generators $\{\pm2,\pm3,\pm7,\pm13,\pm18\}$. Then I think the element $8$ with $|8|=3$ works.

Comment: @Steve, I'd be hard pressed to verify your claim myself.  Do you have a smart way to do it?

Comment: @Ruy: It's a trivial calculation.  Just list out all the elements $8+t$ where $t$ is one of the generators and verify that each one can be written as a sum of two generators, and similarly by brute force verify that $8$ itself cannot be written as a sum of two generators.

Comment: @Eric, that is precisely what I feared $\ddot\smile$